# Java - change label and get error

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception, jlabel, settext

Hello i have trouble with this code.
lblXY is JLabel i want to change text of label to info string which is consisting with an integers X and Y coordinates and some string.

```
String info = "X-"+String.valueOf(x)+" Y-"+String.valueOf(y);
lblXY.setText(info);
```

Error code

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

When i use System.out.println that's works but when i want to change label that isnt work.
Anybody can help me ?

Comment: `Anybody can help me ?` - the error message is telling you the problem. You have a NullPointerExecption. I would guess you didn't define the label.

Comment: where did you initialize lblXY >

Comment: private static javax.swing.JLabel lblXY;
netbeans

Comment: just out of curiosity, can you find anything that looks like  lblXY = new javax.swing.JLabel();  in your code

Comment: Where is the `lblXY = new JLabel();` statement. A variable is null unless you create an instance of the object.

Comment: private void initComponents() {
lblXY = new javax.swing.JLabel();
......
}

Comment: So then whats the problem? If the initComponents() method is executed BEFORE the code that tries to set the text on the label the code should work. We don't have time to play 20 questions. If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okey I initialize

```
lblXY = new JLabel();
```

on the start of function and no error so that works thank's a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Check that your `x` and `y` values are not `null`

Also:

```
JLabel lblXY = new JLabel("");
```

Then:

```
lblXY.setText(info);
```